# All params undefined but attributes has values

Tags: javascript, web-component

Whilst playing around with [custom elements](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-custom-elements/) I notice that the `attachedCallback` function has a populated `attributes` collection. Namely it's a `NamedNodeMap` containing all passed attributes to the element.

I also notice that specifying parameters on the `attachedCallback` function always produces `undefined`.

How is it possible to set up the `attributes` collection within a function but have any specified parameters be `undefined`? Is this purely because of the browser vendor's implementation or is there a way to do this in JavaScript that I'm unaware of?

Example:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
    proto.attachedCallback = function (elem) {
        console.log(elem); // undefined
        console.log(this.attributes); // NamedNodeMap
    };
```

Comment: If you're familiar with way `this` works in JavaScript, this kind of thing isn't all that surprising. http://jsfiddle.net/Lbrujmwc/1/

Comment: Yeah you're right. For some reason I hadn't thought of `attributes` as a property on the function prototype. Seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the stack, a call is being made to `apply` or `call`, where the first argument is an object that contains an `attributes` property.

Here's how you can do it in code:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.attachedCallback = function (elem) {
    console.log(elem); // undefined
    console.log(this.attributes); // NamedNodeMap
};

var randomObjectWithAttributes = {
    attributes: new NamedNodeMap()
};

proto.attachedCallback.call(randomObjectWithAttributes);
```

This is one of the finer points of Javascript, that you can use `call` and `apply` to treat functions as if they belong to an object's prototype even if they don't.

Comment: Thanks Austin. Now that you've pointed this out, it seems obvious. I wasn't thinking of `attributes` as a property of the prototype. Cheers.